# Get current hover/ mouseover element in same nested selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select the currently hover element with a nested selector. I ".frmElement" class as a selector. When I take a mouse on the ".frmElement" element at nth level all the previous selector elements are show the hover effect, but I want to show hover effect only on the hovered selector

This is the selector looks like.

```
|- .frmElement 
 |-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement:hover  
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|- .frmElement
```

I use jquery mouseover event to add a class to it but it add to all parent's, ex. used "active" class to show the hover effect but 'active' class is added to all the parents so it look like

```
|- .frmElement.active
 |-|- .frmElement.active 
 |-|-|- .frmElement.active 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement:hover.active  
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|- .frmElement
```

but I want to add this class to only the element with selector currently mouse pointer is on.

```
|- .frmElement
 |-|- .frmElement
 |-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement:hover.active <--- I want this to be done 
 |-|-|-|- .frmElement 
 |-|-|- .frmElement
```

Here is the actual html, css and JQuery I use https://jsfiddle.net/8b4xg3kt/

Here is the code for html

```
    <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="container" dragula="COPYABLE" id="right" ng-reflect-dragula="COPYABLE">
  <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="tabContainer frmElement" id="Tabbox-1">
    <div class="btns">
      <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.8406219829777923"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.8406219829777923"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="containerFraim tabs">
      <!-- https://codepen.io/WebCamayoc/pen/nLhAa -->
      <div id="tabs">
        <!--Pestaña 1 activa por defecto-->
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab-group" checked="checked">
        <label for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
        <!--Pestaña 2 inactiva por defecto-->
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab-group">
        <label for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
        <!--Contenido a mostrar/ocultar-->
        <div id="content-block">
          <!--Contenido de la Pestaña 1-->
          <div id="content-1">
            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="tabContainer0">
              <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Containerbox frmElement" id="Containerbox-2">
                <div class="btns">
                  <span>
                      <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                      <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.9341944397820223"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
                      <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.9341944397820223"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="containerFraim">
                  <div class="header"> Panel </div>
                  <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Containerbox2">
                    <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Framebox frmElement" id="Framebox-3">
                      <div class="btns">
                        <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.6287785288366226"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.6287785288366226"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
                      </div>

                      <div class="container dropable frameBorder" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Framebox3">
                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Containerbox frmElement" id="Containerbox-4">
                          <div class="btns">
                            <span>
                              <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.2787709275968595"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.2787709275968595"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="containerFraim">
                            <div class="header"> Panel </div>
                            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Containerbox4">
                              <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="rediobox frmElement" id="rediobox-5">
                                <div class="btns">
                                  <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.166250324410125"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.166250324410125"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
                                </div>
                                <label> Radio Options </label>
                                <label><input name="rediobox" disabled="true" type="radio" id="rediobox"> rediobox</label>
                                <label><input name="rediobox" disabled="true" type="radio" id="rediobox-1"> rediobox-1</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="selectbox frmElement" id="selectbox-6">
                          <div class="btns">
                            <span>
                              <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.9360886227539027"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.9360886227539027"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <label> Select Box</label><select id="selectbox" disabled="true"><option>Select</option></select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Contenido de la Pestaña 2-->
          <div id="content-2">
            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="tabContainer1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the element ID on mouse over But it gives me id's of all the parent elements

JS Code :

```
$(document).on("mouseover", '.frmElement', function(e) {
  console.log($(".frmElement:first").index(this));
  console.log($(".frmElement:first", this).attr('class'));
  //e.stopPropagation();
  //console.log(e);
  // console.log($(".frmElement:first", this).attr('id')) ;
  /* var len = $(".frmElement").filter(function(i, el) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(el);
    console.log($(el).attr('id'));
    return $(el);

    // var id = '#'+$(el).attr('id');
    // $(id).addClass('active');
  }); */
  /* console.log('---------');
  console.log(len); */
  // console.log($(this).html()); // jQuery equivalent to this.innerHTML
});
```

CSS :

```
.dropable {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.frmElement {
  margin: 2px 0 10px 2px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; */
  background: #fbfbfb;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=number],
select,
textarea {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.containerFraim div.header {
  background: #eaeaea !important;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

/* Tabs */

#tabs>input {
  height: 2.5em;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px;
}

#tabs>label {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas */
  border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0;
  color: #888;
  /* Color del texto de las pestañas */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  /* Tamaño del texto de las pestañas */
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabs input:hover+label {
  background: #ddd;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas al pasar el cursor por encima */
  color: #666;
  /* Color del texto de las pestañas al pasar el cursor por encima */
}

#tabs input:checked+label {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas al presionar */
  color: #444;
  /* Color de las pestañas al presionar */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  /*
    -webkit-transition: .1s;
    -moz-transition: .1s;
    -o-transition: .1s;
    -ms-transition: .1s;
    */
}

#content-block {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  /* Fondo del contenido */
  border-radius: 0 .25em .25em .25em;
  min-height: 10em;
  /* Alto del contenido */
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  /* z-index: 5; */
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

#content-block>div {
  /* opacity: 0; */
  display: none;
  padding: .5em;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: -100; */
  width: 100%;
  /*
    transition: all linear 0.1s;
    */
}

#tabs input#tab-1:checked~#content-block #content-1,
#tabs input#tab-2:checked~#content-block #content-2,
#tabs input#tab-3:checked~#content-block #content-3 {
  /* opacity: 1; */
  display: block;
  /* z-index: 100; */
}

/* TAB end */

.btns {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  background: #0077ff !important;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.frmElement:hover {
  border: 1px solid #008eff !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px #90ecff inset;
}

/* .frmGen .frmElement:hover div.btns{ */

.frmElement:hover+.btns {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: you could just give it another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up. So a hover on a child/nested element won't cause a ripple effect and prevent the parent element from being classified as hovered thus targetting just the current element.

```js
$('.frmElement').on('mouseover', function(e){ 
  $(this).addClass('hover'); 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
})

$('.frmElement').on('mouseout', function(){ 
  $(this).removeClass('hover') 
 })
```

```css
.dropable {
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.frmElement {
  margin: 2px 0 10px 2px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; */
  background: #fbfbfb;
  position: relative;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=number],
select,
textarea {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.containerFraim div.header {
  background: #eaeaea !important;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

/* Tabs */

#tabs>input {
  height: 2.5em;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px;
}

#tabs>label {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas */
  border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0;
  color: #888;
  /* Color del texto de las pestañas */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  /* Tamaño del texto de las pestañas */
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabs input:hover+label {
  background: #ddd;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas al pasar el cursor por encima */
  color: #666;
  /* Color del texto de las pestañas al pasar el cursor por encima */
}

#tabs input:checked+label {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  /* Fondo de las pestañas al presionar */
  color: #444;
  /* Color de las pestañas al presionar */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  /*
 -webkit-transition: .1s;
 -moz-transition: .1s;
 -o-transition: .1s;
 -ms-transition: .1s;
 */
}

#content-block {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  /* Fondo del contenido */
  border-radius: 0 .25em .25em .25em;
  min-height: 10em;
  /* Alto del contenido */
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  /* z-index: 5; */
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

#content-block>div {
  /* opacity: 0; */
  display: none;
  padding: .5em;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: -100; */
  width: 100%;
  /*
 transition: all linear 0.1s;
 */
}

#tabs input#tab-1:checked~#content-block #content-1,
#tabs input#tab-2:checked~#content-block #content-2,
#tabs input#tab-3:checked~#content-block #content-3 {
  /* opacity: 1; */
  display: block;
  /* z-index: 100; */
}

/* TAB end */

.btns {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  background: #0077ff !important;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.frmElement.hover {
  border: 1px solid #008eff !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px #90ecff inset;
}

/* .frmGen .frmElement:hover div.btns{ */

.frmElement:hover+.btns {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="container" dragula="COPYABLE" id="right" ng-reflect-dragula="COPYABLE">
  <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="tabContainer frmElement" id="Tabbox-1">
    <div class="btns">
      <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.8406219829777923"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.8406219829777923"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="containerFraim tabs">
      <!-- https://codepen.io/WebCamayoc/pen/nLhAa -->
      <div id="tabs">
        <!--Pestaña 1 activa por defecto-->
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab-group" checked="checked">
        <label for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
        <!--Pestaña 2 inactiva por defecto-->
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab-group">
        <label for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
        <!--Contenido a mostrar/ocultar-->
        <div id="content-block">
          <!--Contenido de la Pestaña 1-->
          <div id="content-1">
            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="tabContainer0">
              <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Containerbox frmElement" id="Containerbox-2">
                <div class="btns">
                  <span>
             <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
             <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.9341944397820223"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
             <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.9341944397820223"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
           </span>
                </div>
                <div class="containerFraim">
                  <div class="header"> Panel </div>
                  <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Containerbox2">
                    <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Framebox frmElement" id="Framebox-3">
                      <div class="btns">
                        <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.6287785288366226"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.6287785288366226"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
                      </div>

                      <div class="container dropable frameBorder" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Framebox3">
                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="Containerbox frmElement" id="Containerbox-4">
                          <div class="btns">
                            <span>
                              <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.2787709275968595"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.2787709275968595"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="containerFraim">
                            <div class="header"> Panel </div>
                            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="Containerbox4">
                              <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="rediobox frmElement" id="rediobox-5">
                                <div class="btns">
                                  <span>
          <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.166250324410125"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.166250324410125"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </span>
                                </div>
                                <label> Radio Options </label>
                                <label><input name="rediobox" disabled="true" type="radio" id="rediobox"> rediobox</label>
                                <label><input name="rediobox" disabled="true" type="radio" id="rediobox-1"> rediobox-1</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="selectbox frmElement" id="selectbox-6">
                          <div class="btns">
                            <span>
                              <button type="button" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="clone" id="clone_0.9360886227539027"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></button>
                              <button type="button" class="remove" id="remove_0.9360886227539027"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <label> Select Box</label><select id="selectbox" disabled="true"><option>Select</option></select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Contenido de la Pestaña 2-->
          <div id="content-2">
            <div class="container dropable" dragula="COPYABLE" id="tabContainer1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running up against the browser's definition of what a "hover" is. The browser generally thinks hovers on children qualify as hovers on parents as well.

You could defeat this with custom `mouseover` + `mouseout`, and calling `event.stopPropagation` to avoid also interacting with parent elements. This isn't a native browser event so there's no pseudoclass like `:hover` available; instead we'll add/remove a custom css class `.hovered`.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hoverable')).forEach(hoverable => {
  hoverable.addEventListener('mouseover', evt => {
    hoverable.classList.add('hovered');
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });
  hoverable.addEventListener('mouseout', evt => {
    hoverable.classList.remove('hovered');
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.hoverable {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #c00000;
}
.hoverable.hovered {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable h1">
  <div class="hoverable h2">
    <div class="hoverable h3">
      <div class="hoverable h4">
        <div class="hoverable h5">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```